# Are there any risks adding some custom fields on Standard objects in a managed package?

Tags: managed-package

There is a 900 maximum hard limit on the total custom fields per object allowed from Salesforce Help [Custom Fields Allowed Per Object](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_field_allocations.htm&type=5) doc.

In that case, can my managed package be installed successfully if a customer org Lead object has reached this limit(900 custom fields) and my managed package has some custom fields on Lead object?

Comment: This is a risk, and would prevent install, since this maximum is shared across all packages and subscriber fields on an org. However, there's a bigger risk in the limit of 15 cross-object relationships across all custom cross-object formula fields on an object, so if you add cross-object formula fields in your package you are far more likely to hit these limits.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks. I also got a similar answer from Salesforce team at here: https://partners.salesforce.com/0D54V00006E9JFU